# Como validar que una cadena tenga un formato obligatorio C#

Tags: c#

estoy intento buscar como puedo validar que una cadena de texto en c# Sting tenga el siguiente formato igual a este = 31,30,30,30,30,30,30 ya que los necesito así tal cual y no puede haber un numero mas o numero menos deben ser siempre 14 números  y separados por coma (,) cada dos números como indique en la cadena de números.

Gracias quien me ayude la verdad no encuentro por ningún lado como hacerlo.

Comment: Recuerda poner lo que has intentado

Comment: Para entenderte mejor que es lo que pretendes hacer con lo que pides

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes utilizar expresiones regulares ([Regex](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular)) para tu problema.
regex tal cual, es un patrón específico que puedes utilizar para buscar en cualquier `string`. para este ejemplo, utilicé una herramienta en línea para generar y comprobarla.
la herramienta en cuestión te la dejo en el siguiente enlace: [Regex builder](https://regex101.com/).

Basado en ello, y con C#, creé el siguiente código, con sus debidos comentarios para su interpretación:
**EDIT: para evitar que la cadena traiga datos extras, compararemos que su longitud sea 20.**

```
            //solicitamos el string
            Console.WriteLine(@"Inserta un formato \d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\");
            string result = Console.ReadLine();
            /*creamos la expresion regular que necesitamos
             * \d significa que solicita un dígito.
             * \, significa que necesita una coma.
             * este código sólo funcionará si la expresión regular concuerda.
             */
            Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d\,\d\d");
            //método que evalúa la expresión regular con el dato que obtuvimos por ReadLine();
            //14 dígitos + 6 comas=20 caracteres; si no son 20 exactos, no debe de concordar.
            if (rgx.IsMatch(result) && result.Length==20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Concuerda");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No concuerda");
            }
```

Comment: Oye sirvió muchas gracias solo existe un problema al final de la cadena si agrego así 78,78,78,78,78,78,78 sirve bien pero si agrego un numero de mas al final o al principio  (978,78,78,78,78,78,789) ejemplo el 9 se agrega y no debería permitir ese numero de mas al final o principio solo pueden haber 14 números

Comment: podríamos validar la longitud de la cadena, para evitar que tenga más caracteres de los necesarios, ¿quieres que edite mi pregunta para mostrarte?

Comment: me ayudarías bastante en la parte de expresiones regulares si me complico demasiado cuando son validaciones para cadenas diferentes a las habituales, te lo agradezco si la editas

Comment: editada, espero te sirva :)